# Run and debug on all devices, android, IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, device

Is there anything similar to:

> open 'project properties'-->'Run/Debug settings'-->'{My project}'-->'{target}'-->'Launch on all compatible devics/AVD's '

That can be found in eclipse, but for IntelliJ?

Comment: Android Run configuration, **Show chooser dialog**, multiple selection is allowed and persists after launching.

Comment: But what if a new device is connected afterwards? I would like to always launch on all devices, even if new device is connected... Otherwise it is clunky and wastes time...